# Inject connection string to DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ninject

I have external service which I can't modify, but I can only add new Class Libraries to it to extent it's functionality. My problem is that my class library uses EF->Repository->Service and IOC container and when I attach my library to external service it does not work as this service has no Connection String defined. I found that I can user Service Locator to define implement IOC container in my Class Library:

```
internal class ServiceLocator
{
    static ServiceLocator()
    {
        Current = new DefaultServiceLocator();
    }

    public static IServiceLocator Current { get; }

    private sealed class DefaultServiceLocator : IServiceLocator
    {
        private readonly IKernel _kernel;  // Ninject kernel

        public DefaultServiceLocator()
        {
            _kernel = new StandardKernel();
            LoadBindings();
        }

        public T Get<T>()
        {
            return _kernel.Get<T>();
        }

        private void LoadBindings()
        {

            string name = ""; // connection string
            _kernel.Bind<DbContext>().ToConstructor(_ => new Entities(name));
            _kernel.Bind<IRegionService>().To<RegionService>();
            _kernel.Bind<IRegionRepository>().To<RegionRepository>();
            _kernel.Bind<IMapper>().ToConstant(AutoMapperConfig.Initialize());
        }
    }
}
```

I created my own partial class to pass connection string to the constructor:

```
public partial class Entities
{
    public Entities(string name)
        :base(name)
    {
    }
}
```

as auto-generated class does not allow to pass connection string (and I don't want to modify this):

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext
{
   public Entities()
    : base("name=Entities")
   {
   }
}
```

When I run my test application in debug mode I see that it refers to auto-generated DbContext class instead to this created by me. As I said earlier I can't modify external service to just add connection string into App.config file. Kindly provide me any possible solutions to my problem. I am open to design changes.

Comment: I don't understand this: "When I run my test application in debug mode I see that it refers to auto-generated DbContext class instead to this created by me." When you add a partial class of another, than it's still the same class, but possibly defined in more files, so eventually you should have just only one class in your solution. Or did you create your partial class in different namespace or even assembly?

Comment: @JanMuncinsky I wan that my class library will instantiate public Entities(string name):base(name) rather than public Entities() : base("name=Entities"). In second case test application tries to search Entities connection string in App.config file. What I want to do is to hard code connection string in my Class Library and invoke Entities(string name):base(name). Does it explain what I want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that some of your classes expect `Entities` dependency instead of `DbContext`. In this case Ninject tends to fallback to implicit self-binding and chooses constructor with dependencies that be can resolved (default in this case).

Try this binding instead:

`_kernel.Bind<Entities>().ToConstructor(_ => new Entities(name));`